# Excel VBA to extract information from two different text files

Tags: vba, excel

Greeting, have a little bit of a dilemma. I'm making a VBA that will allow the user to open two separate text files and use them to graph data. So far, I've been successful with getting the two text files open in one spreadsheet. The problem I'm having is using the data from one text file (12 digit numbers) and comparing that to the other text file, which is a log of data. The first text file has a bunch of irrelevant information, but I only need to take the date and 12 digit number recorded. The second text file has a list of 12 digit numbers which I want to check against the first text file and get a count of how many times each specific number came up. Using that, I want to just have a regular count of times it has occurred. I need this to be a VBA because the user that will be opening this macro won't have any programming knowledge so it needs to be very simple.

Also to note, the badge numbers CAN be different based on the text file uploaded, but they are always added in the same located of the spreadsheet.

Thanks.

EDIT: Tried to make a rough sketch of what I'm talking about

```
  |  A  |  B              |  C           |              D         |                     

  |  1  | DATA WITH NUMBER|   ...........|........... |NUMBER TO COMPARE WITH |  
  |  2  | DATA WITH NUMBER|
```

Comment: Adding sample data to the question might help get better picture!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully grasp what you want, but it sounds like you want to use the Dictionary class in VBA.

You would need to add a reference to the MS Scripting Runtime library, and your code to read the second input file (to count occurrences) could look something like this:

```
  Dim counts As Object
  Dim splitValue As Variant
  Dim inputLine as String

  Set counts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Open "yourfile.txt" For Input As #1
  Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, inputLine

    splitValues = Split(inputLine, vbTab)

    If counts.Exists(splitValues(0)) Then
      counts(splitValues(0)) = counts(splitValues(0)) + 1
    Else
      counts.Add splitValues(0), 1
    End If

  Loop

  Close #1
```

Then, when you read the first file, you could essentially call the dictionary to find how many occurrences of the badge number appeared in the second file.

```
occurrences = counts(badgeNumber)
```

Again, I may be off.  If you can clarify what both inputs look like and what you want the final output to look like, it would help.